# Bokeh Dodge Chart using Different Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, bokeh

everyone! So I have 2 **dataframes** extracted from Pro-Football-Reference as a csv and run through Pandas with the aid of StringIO.

I'm pasting only the header and a row of the info right below:

```
data_1999 = StringIO("""Tm,W,L,W-L%,PF,PA,PD,MoV,SoS,SRS,OSRS,DSRS Indianapolis Colts,13,3,.813,423,333,90,5.6,0.5,6.1,6.6,-0.5""")

data = StringIO("""Tm,W,L,T,WL%,PF,PA,PD,MoV,SoS,SRS,OSRS,DSRS Indianapolis Colts,10,6,0,.625,433,344,89,5.6,-2.2,3.4,3.9,-0.6""")
```

And then interpreted normally using pandas.read_csv, creating 2 different **dataframes** called **df_nfl_1999** and **df_nfl** respectively.

So I was trying to use Bokeh and do something like [here](https://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/categorical.html#visual-dodge), except instead of 'apples' and 'pears' would be the name of the teams being the main grouping. I tried to emulate it by using only Pandas Dataframe info:

```
p9=figure(title='Comparison 1999 x 2018',background_fill_color='#efefef',x_range=df_nfl_1999['Tm'])
p9.xaxis.axis_label = 'Team'
p9.yaxis.axis_label = 'Variable'
p9.vbar(x=dodge(df_nfl_1999['Tm'],0.0,range=p9.x_range),top=df_nfl_1999['PF'],legend='PF in 1999', width=0.3)
p9.vbar(x=dodge(df_nfl_1999['Tm'],0.25,range=p9.x_range),top=df_nfl['PF'],legend='PF in 2018', width=0.3, color='#A6CEE3')
show(p9)
```

And the error I got was:

> ValueError: expected an element of either String, Dict(Enum('expr',
>   'field', 'value', 'transform'), Either(String, Instance(Transform),
>   Instance(Expression), Float)) or Float, got {'field': 0
>   Washington Redskins

My initial idea was to group by Team Name (**df_nfl['Tm']**), analyzing the points in favor in each year (so **df_nfl['PF']** for 2018 and **df_nfl_1999['PF']** for 1999). A simple offset of the columns could resolve, but I can't seem to find a way to do this, other than the dodge chart, and it's not really working (I'm a newbie).

By the way, the error reference is appointed at happening on the:

```
p9.vbar(x=dodge(df_nfl_1999['Tm'],0.0,range=p9.x_range),top=df_nfl_1999['PF'],legend='PF in 1999', width=0.3)
```

I could use a scatter plot, for example, and both charts would coexist, and in some cases overlap (if the data is the same), but I was really aiming at plotting it side by side. The other answers related to the subject usually have older versions of Bokeh with deprecated functions.

Any way I can solve this? Thanks!

**Edit:**

Here is the .head() method. The other one will return exactly the same categories, columns and rows, except that obviously the data changes since it's from a different season.

```
                    Tm   W   L   W-L%   PF   PA   PD  MoV  SoS  SRS  OSRS  \
0  Washington Redskins  10   6  0.625  443  377   66  4.1 -1.3  2.9   6.8   
1       Dallas Cowboys   8   8  0.500  352  276   76  4.8 -1.6  3.1  -0.3   
2      New York Giants   7   9  0.438  299  358  -59 -3.7  0.7 -3.0  -1.8   
3    Arizona Cardinals   6  10  0.375  245  382 -137 -8.6 -0.2 -8.8  -5.5   
4  Philadelphia Eagles   5  11  0.313  272  357  -85 -5.3  1.1 -4.2  -3.3   

   DSRS  
0  -3.9  
1   3.4  
2  -1.2  
3  -3.2  
4  -0.9
```

And the value of executing just `x=dodge` returns:

> dodge() missing 1 required positional argument: 'value'

By adding that argumento `value=0.0` or `value=0.2` the error returned is the same as the original post.

Comment: What is the value of executing just `dodge(df_nfl_1999['Tm']`? Can you add the output of `df.head` for the dataframes?

Comment: Hey, @bigreddot I just edited the post with the information you asked.

Answer (score 1):

The first argument to `dodge` should a single *column name* of a column in a `ColumnDataSource`. The effect is then that any values from that column are dodged by the specified amount when used as coordinates.

You are trying to pass the *contents* of a column, which is is not expected. It's hard to say for sure without complete code to test, but you most likely want

```
x=dodge('Tm', ...)
```

However, you will also need to actually use an explicit Bokeh `ColumnDataSource` and pass that as `source` to `vbar` as is done in the example you link. You can construct one explicitly, but often times you can also just pass the dataframe directly `source=df`, and it will be adapted.

Comment: Bokeh scatter and line work fine without ColumnDataSource, and if I use only one dataframe as reference (without dodge or grouped or anything, just a simple bar plot) it works fine as well. Any idea if I could use the dodge only with pandas?

Comment: Bokeh always uses a ColumnDataSource, it just creates one for you automatically in simple cases. But if you want/need to refer to the columns directly (i.e. to use to configure a `dodge`) then the CDS needs to be explicit. Often you can just pass the dataframe itself as `source` and it will be converted.